# Extract first n characters from each element of a numpy string array

Tags: arrays, string, numpy

I have a NumPy array which elements are strings.
For example

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array(["abcde", "degag"])
```

I need to extract the first n characters from each element of the array (substr/strleft).
The result for the first 3 characters should be an aray like this one:

```
array(['abc', 'deg'], dtype='<U3')
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's almost staring you in the face:

```
In [93]: a = np.array(["abcde", "degag"])
In [94]: a.astype('U3')
Out[94]: array(['abc', 'deg'], dtype='<U3')
```

otherwise you have to iterate

```
In [95]: [s[:3] for s in a]
Out[95]: ['abc', 'deg']
```